# What's window.onunload?

Tags: javascript

Im a beginner and i see that line of code a lot on javascript files , for example  :

```
window.onunload=function(){};
```

when should i use this and what is it role exactly ?

thank you .

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) (For all JavaScript related things, just look it up on MDN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) is an event that is triggered when the user navigates away from your page, or when the page is "unloaded".

It's triggered when a user follows a link, or closes the tab.  It's used for clean up.  Like saving a user's data when they leave the page.  Usually it's paired with [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) (which is called before [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) is using the same criteria) to warn a user that they have unsaved data.

Answer (score 4):

This function gets called when the user closes the browser or navigates away from the page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload

You also might want to check out [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), which allows you to prompt the user with a confirmation message before leaving the page.  This can be useful for reminding the user to save their changes, or making sure the user doesn't actually want to claim their free iPad 2.

Comment: You can only return a string from `onbeforeunload`, not `onunload`.

Answer (score 0):

if a page has an **onunload** handler, browsers that restore the page **state** (remembering changed form field values, script environment) when you navigate away and back to the page do not-
that is, they load the page as if it was the first time it was opened, with no user applied changes.